# Anylogic: How do I converge 2 queues into one delay block?

Tags: anylogic

I'm new to Anylogic, and I was wondering if it's possible to have two queues go into one delay block. I'm trying to simulate products coming from 2 separate welding robots that then go into a sandblasting (delay block) installation. This installation can either blast 3 products from one robot or 1 from the other robot.

Maybe it's also possible to have one delay process be blocked as long as the other one is working, and then unblock it as soon as the other one is finished?

Here's a [picture of the process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKrsS.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

So this is one way of doing it... I added hold blocks after each queue... one of the hold blocks is initially blocked. 
[image: using hold blocks]

I added a button to toggle the state of the hold block:

```
hold.toggleBlock();
hold1.toggleBlock();
```

This is the basic structure... of course the way you block/unblock the holds is up to you.